# convert "M" address to "3" address LTC

Tags: address, litecoin, p2sh, p2pkh

currently im facing with 1 issue that i need to convert all my litecoin address in my fullnode to legacy address (prefix with "M"). Im know that we have a tool https://litecoin-project.github.io/p2sh-convert/ that can help me solve this, but my system currently dev with java, so im asking there is any convert that wrote by java support me this problem ??

Thank for read

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, to do this conversion all you need to do is:

1. decode the address using `base58check`
2. change the first byte from `0x32` to `0x5`
3. encode using `base58check`